# Boiling Beef Chorizo as part of a soup base?

Tags: meat, oil, beef, soup, boiling

I'm wondering about the results if I were to try boiling beef chorizo instead of frying it for use as part of a soup. (My girlfriend insists this is a recipe for disaster, so I'm asking for more information here rather than try it on my own.) Chorizo is oily and is generally cooked by frying, so I'm wondering how the spices and flavors would mix and separate if boiled in water instead of being fried. I'm not particularly skilled at cooking meat, so any information about how I could expect this to turn out would be appreciated. If I boil water, and add chorizo, what could I expect from this? What about if I add it straight to soup to simmer/boil there?

Comment: Welcome to the site @Jonathan. Your question is unfortunately not a good one for this site's format. It's very broad, based on opinion rather than facts, and it's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. I suggest re-formatting it to ask specific questions, for example whether it would be better to boil the chorizo or add it at the end.

Comment: Hello Jonathan, I'm afraid GdD is right. Nobody can tell you whether the results will taste good to *you*, or to your girlfriend. The only way to know is to try it. But the question has no universal answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try and change the question to be more specific.

Comment: I tried making some changes to narrow it down, but it's possible that the question is still too broad, so if that's the case I may need to simply find out on my own.

Comment: I just saw this in the reopen queue - it looks a lot better. The one thing I'm wondering is if you mean to boil it in water, take it out, then add it to soup (the question kind of sounds like that) or just simmer/boil it in the soup directly.

Comment: @Jefromi I was considering both options, ideally I'd like information about both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fry it off with your veg base, remove it, make your soup and then add the chorizo to serve. Boiling chorizo is just a bit of a waste

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? You lost me at veg base. Assume you're talking to someone with no formal understanding of cooking, being as literal and detailed as possible would really make a huge difference.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be more helpful this time. In classical French cooking just about everything begins with a mirepois, which is your veg base, traditionally consisting of equal parts brown onion, carrot and celery. Capsicum and leek are also often used, personally I also use fennel but not carrot. I would thinly slice the chorizo, heat a heavy based pot with a tablespoon of vegetable oil and when it's (technically speaking) really fucking hot drop in the chorizo and immediately remove the pot from the heat whilst stirring the chorizo until the pot cools.

Comment: Drop the burner to the lowest setting and add about 100grams of butter, simmer for one or two minutes and then remove the chorizo with a slotted spoon or tongs. You'll have a red tinged chorizo infused butter which you can add your vegetables to, onions first.

Comment: Awesome, that clarifies exactly what I needed to know. Would you mind editing your comment into your answer? It's up to you, but I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Ive tried this a few times.  I think boiling the chorizo can be beneficial for some soups because it allows the flavor to penetrate the other components.  However, boiling it also makes the meat pretty indistiguishable and mostly just imparts flavors to the soup (in my case ive used mexican chorizo).  Maybe another thing to think about would be the oil content which could allow you to craft a flavorful rue.  rue is made from simering equal amounts of oil and flour on low heat (timing wise less is more) and will thicken your soup.